# How do I improve at these types of questions?

Tags: soft-question, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

[Find the smallest cosntant $k>0$ such that $\frac{ab}{a+b+2c} + \frac{bc}{b+c+2a} + \frac{ca}{c+a+2b} \leq k(a+b+c)$ for every $a,b,c>0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288816/find-the-smallest-cosntant-k0-such-that-fracabab2c-fracbcbc2a)

Basically, questions that involve solving or making sense of equations with like 5 variables and no context. There's a lot of those kinds of questions on contest maths, but I cannot for the life of me solve them. Is there a nice way to approach them or are they all different?

Comment: at first set $$a=b=c$$

Comment: for this type of inequality set $$a+b+c=1$$

Comment: How do you account that optimum value incurs at your mentioned constraint.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $$y= \frac{abc}{x({a+b+c}+x)}$$

Clearly the function is decreasing for positive x and is concave upwards.(You might want to apply first and second derivative test, if you want)

[click this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBQbK.png)(another 'merit' of my reputation)

The centroid the triangle(brown dot in my diagram) lies always above the curve. I am sure you can take it from there.